# 403 with accessing Hosted IIS server

Tags: iis, asp.net, http-status-code-403

A client has several servers hosted which are running IIS 7.  From any other server within the same hosting server there are no problems accessing our ASP.net website but from the clients office they get a 403 error with no sub code.

I've checked the IIS logs, there is nothing being logged for the remote attempts. I've also enabled Failed Request Tracing, there is also nothing being logged. I've verified all logging is working from within the hosted domain (from a different server).

When we try to telnet to port 80 on the IIS server it succeeds from the clients office and when I stop the website in IIS then telnet fails so it looks as if it's getting to the server.

I've created a simple IIS site that simply serves up an Image, this has the same issue.  I've also enabled Anonymous authentication and impersonation in the web.config which again works from a server in the same subnet but not the client site.

The hosting provider assures us that port 80 is open and that we shouldn't have any problems.

Using the DevTools in chrome simply shows 403 and gives an error viewing the response object.

Comment: Did you try to send a request using telnet? Like `GET / HTTP/1.0`?

Comment: No, would that just inform us if the server can accept HTTP requests from the remote client?

Comment: You'd see what happens if an actual request is made like response headers and there should be response headers since you at least GET a 403. Also you should see if telnet is actually connected to your server, because you should be seeing the 403s in the server logs which you are not. If anything it might be that the connections from your client to your server are intercepted by whatever like an AV-solution. So far you only know telnet and also Chrome are connected to something but not to what.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.  The fact when I stop the Website in IIS the telnet to port 80 fails suggests it's reaching the server.

Comment: It does suggest that yes but if it really is the IIS responding with a 403 you should be able to see the actual reply which Chrome doesn't seem to show you.

Comment: When trying the telnet request we get a 400 error saying the request has an invalid header name